# how to show menu->submenu->submenu->submenu wordpress

Tags: wordpress

[image]

I want to show this type of menu. All are showing except last sub menu in red color. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Image Is not much clear.what is the final output you need ?

Comment: the last menus are not showing which is in red color. Its coming using walker wordpress class I increased that depth to 5 but no change.

Comment: Please a show your codes

Answer (score 0):

This will get you started.

Use `wp_nav()`to start building out a navigation with multiple sub-levels.

Check it out on the [Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/)